# jquery serialize a div content to post input data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, forms, serialization

I'm trying to use the jQuery.serialize() function, generally used on form, to serialize data inside a div.

I can't use the form tag as I'm working in asp.net webforms that wraps everything inside a form, so nested form doesn't work.

Here is my js code:

```
$('div.request input.submit-button').on('click', function () {
var form = $(this).parent();

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/API/InfoRequest.ashx',
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (response) {           

            }
        })
});
```

but $(form).serialize() return an empty string.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div role="form" id="sidebar-form"  class="request">
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="name3">Nome</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name3" placeholder="Nome e Cognome" name="name3">
    <i class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback"></i>
</div>
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="email3">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email3" placeholder="Indirizzo Email" name="email3">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope form-control-feedback"></i>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Categoria</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="category">
        <option value="Sales">Vendita</option>
        <option value="Support">Tecnica</option>
        <option value="Lorem">Logistica</option>
        <option value="Ipsum sit">Ipsum sit</option>
        <option value="Dolor amet">Dolor amet</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label for="message3">Messaggio</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="message3" placeholder="" name="message3"></textarea>
    <i class="fa fa-pencil form-control-feedback"></i>
</div>
<input type="button" value="INVIA" class="submit-button btn btn-primary">
</div>
```

I want to retrieve only the form fields, like input, select, textarea, post them as form urlencoded and then read them in the called ASHX handler.

Is it possible using serialize()?

Comment: Since you're not actually using a `<form>` tag `$(form)` which is the selection criteria in jquery will not work.

Comment: @BRogers, I also thought so, then I noticed it's `$(form)`, not `$("form")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('#sidebar-form :input, #sidebar-form textarea,  #sidebar-form select').serialize();
```

Or

```
$("#sidebar-form").find("select, textarea, input").serialize()
```

Comment: I have made it this way: $(form).find("input,select,textarea").serialize()

Comment: Yeah, that would work. Although, it is technically not a 'form' and the naming could be a bit confusing. Maybe _container_?

Answer (score 0):

you will have to build your own function for that

```
function formSerializer(selector){
  data="";
   // look for every form field
  selector.find('input, select, textarea').each(function(){
     // serialize data
    data+=$(this).attr("name")+"="$(this).val()+"&";
  });
// remove the last & char
return data.replace(/&$/g,"");
}
```

function call

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/API/InfoRequest.ashx',
        data: formSerializer(form),
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (response) {           

        }
    })
```