# how do i send ajax request by using onclick event without form enclosed tags in django

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

[this is image that i want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvvR1.png)actually i have a div content,i have apply onclick event on that div when user click on that div the text between these tags should be sent to server and then display in the table as well.i have done something guid me where is the error actually,because `$.ajax` not working it raising an error

> e.g: $.ajax is not fnction

**players.html**

```
                         <div class="selectize-control single">
                         <div class="selectize-input items has-options not-full">
                         <input type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="" 
                    id="select_player" style="width: 146.75px; opacity: 1; position: 
                         relative; left: 0px;" placeholder="Adauga jucator la echipa">
                         </div>

                         <div class="selectize-dropdown single liststyle" id="listitems" 
                      style="display: None; width: 987px; top: 29px; left: 0px; visibility: 
                        visible;">

                             <div class="selectize-dropdown-content">
                                     {% block listplayers %}
                                          {% if player is not None %}
                                              {% for p in player %}
                                 <div class="option selected curserstyle sp" id="{{p.id}}" data-selectable="" data-value="{{p.YourName}}">{{p.YourName}}1</div>
                                 <div class="option selected curserstyle sp" id="49" data-selectable="" data-value="{{p.YourName}}">{{p.YourName}}2</div>

                                 {% endfor %}
                                          {% else %}
                                 <div class="text-center">
                                              List is Empty
                                 </div>
                                          {% endif %}
                                 {% endblock %}
                     </div>
                     </div>
                     </div>
```

**javascript**

```
                 $("#listitems").on('click',function(e){

    // preventing from page reload and default actions
    e.preventDefault();
    // serialize the data for sending the form data.
    var serializedData = $(this).serialize();
    // make POST ajax call

    $.ajax({
    type:'get',
    url:"/templates/dashboard/players",
    data:serializedData,
    success:function(responce){

                            // on successfull creating object
                            // 1. clear the form.

                            $("#listitems").trigger('reset');

                            // 2. focus to nickname input

                            $(".sp").focus();
                            // display the newly friend to table.
                            var instance = JSON.parse(response["instance"]);
                            var fields = instance[0]["fields"];
                             var x = document.getElementById(user_id).textContent;


                            $("#playername").append('<div class="row list-row player-row " id="targetdel'+i+'"><div class="col-md-6 title"><a id="playername" href="#">'+x+'</a></div><div class="col-md-2 company text-center has-checkbox"><label class="green checkbox-box"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_entity checkbox_captain" id="captain"  data-entity_id="17270" data-entity_type="captain" data-url_ajax="update_team_player"><span class="checkmark"></span></label></div> <div class="col-md-2 company text-center has-checkbox"> <label class="green checkbox-box "><input type="checkbox" class=" checkbox_entity checkbox_observer " id="cd_btn" data-entity_id="'+i+'" data-entity_type="observer" data-url_ajax="update_team_player style="background-color:black;" "> <span class="checkmark"></span> </label></div><div class="col-md-2 actions company text-right"><a href="" class="remove_entity_data" data-entity_id="17270" data-entity_type="team_player" > </a><button id = "'+i+'" class="btn del" style="text-transform: none;background-color: #ed143d00;padding: 0px 9px;border: none;color: #a2a2a2;">x</button></div></div>');
                            i++;
                },
                    error: function (response) {
                    // alert the error if any error occured
                    alert("this one is error");
                    alert(response["responseJSON"]["error"]);
                    },
    })


    })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jquery serialize a div content to post input data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42635362/jquery-serialize-a-div-content-to-post-input-data)

Comment: no its not work for me

Comment: One glaring issue I see is that in your `success` of the ajax you have `function(responce)` but then proceed to use `response` in the success

Comment: @James when i use onclick its says $.ajax is not a function,

Comment: Where is the onclick? The code above doesn't show any on click or submit

Comment: i have update my question.please you can check this as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from you using `response` in the `success` of the ajax when you have `function(responce)`, you may be using the slim build of Jquery.

You should make sure you are using the full version of Jquery as the slim build for some reason does not have `ajax` included in it.

An easy way to check is to go to where you have defined your scripts and see whether your script has `slim` in it.

This is, I believe, the latest full version of jquery. This is what you should have.

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>`

not this

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>`

Comment: No, not both. Remove the `slim` that, if you had that added, would be causing the issue as this does NOT have `ajax in it`. Does it work with the full version added?

Comment: @Arslanminko Does everything seem to be working correctly now?

Comment: no sir i have tried my best but still it did not fixed.

Comment: @Arslanminko No problem!